# Ansible multiple inventory file

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use multiple inventory file and dynamic inventory with Ansible 1.4 and dev. Ansible returns **No hosts matched**.

I have a simulated scenario with two hosts file in a directory *test* the content of the directory is listed.

*hosts1.ini*

```
[group1]
test1    ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1
test2    ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.2
[group2]
test3    ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.3
```

*hosts2.ini*

```
[group3]
test4     ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.4
[group4]
test5    ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.4
test6    ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.5
```

if I run *ansible -i test --list-hosts all* it returns **No hosts matched**.

I digged into the code and found dir.py with a small amended i got it too work. But I think i must have done something wrong and the hack is not required.
Any ideas on how to solve it ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Remove the `.ini` from your file names:

```
$ ls test/
hosts1  hosts2

$ ansible -i test --list-hosts all 
    test1
    test2
    test3
    test5
    test6
    test4
```

Answer (score 3):

If you come to this question and want to use multiple inventories from different locations, just specify the `-i` parameter multiple times:

```
ansible -i test -i another/path/to/inventory --list-hosts all
```

Be aware, that the group vars of the last specified inventory will be used for all inventories.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [INVENTORY_IGNORE_EXTS](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#inventory-ignore-exts)
i.e. in the [ansible.cfg](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#the-configuration-file):

```
[inventory]
ignore_extensions = {{(REJECT_EXTS + ('.orig', '.cfg', '.retry'))}}
```

or

```
[defaults]
inventory_ignore_extension = {{(REJECT_EXTS + ('.orig', '.cfg', '.retry'))}}
```

or via environment variable

```sh
ANSIBLE_INVENTORY_IGNORE='{{(REJECT_EXTS + ('.orig', '.cfg', '.retry'))}}' ansible --list-hosts all
```