# working with multiple yaml inventory files in ansible

Tags: ansible

is multiple inventories possible for yaml files just like ini files as mentioned in the below link ?
[Ansible multiple inventory file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638996/ansible-multiple-inventory-file)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works the same with ini, yaml, dynamic inventory sources, or combinations of static and dynamic inventory.

You can test this yourself:

```
ansible-inventory -i path/to/yaml/files/ --list
```

Relevant documentation link: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#using-inventory-directories-and-multiple-inventory-sources